# Report Models in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

Folks.

I am responsible for converting a VS2008 Report Model Project (.SMDLPROJ) into its "equivalent" form under VS2017.  Obviously, Report Models are no longer supported under SSDT for VS2017 (otherwise, I wouldn't be posting to this web site).  If someone could point me in the right direction it would be most appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually SQL Server 2017 AND 2019 still support report models, BUT you need to deploy them from within a visual studio project (get BIDS from a SQL Server 2008 R2 installation). Trying to upload a .smdl file will fail.